# Routing page based on UserRole ASP.NET Core MVC web app

Tags: web, asp.net-core-mvc

In my web application, how can I route the user based on `UserRole` after login? The `UserRole` was retrieved from the JWT token and also I put it in the API response. The token is issued by my auth server.

How do I secure the routing? If the JWT is intercepted and the role is changed to admin, could the user then access to admin page?

I'm still new in doing this kind development, so some insight is very much appreciated.

```
UserDetails userDetails = new UserDetails();
TokenResponse result = await servicex.Login(ProcEmail, ProcPassword);

if (result.Success)
{
    userDetails.SetUserDetailsFromTokenResponse(result, _httpContextAccessor);
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard");
}

return View("loginPage");
```

And in my dashboard controller, I tried policy but it returns a "HTTP ERROR 401" error.

```
public class DashboardController : Controller
{
    //[Authorize(Policy = IdentityData.AdminUserPolicyName)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> IndexAsync()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

[My System Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qelul.png)

I'm expecting the routing based on `UserRole` to be safe

Comment: the userRole will always be available... so you can update the UI accordingly.  For instance, if the user does not have Admin role, you don't show the link to Admin Panel.   Your authorize attribute will protect the endpoint(s).  (In case they manually go to the endpoint...)   The claims in the JWT cannot be changed.  (You'd have to issue a new one to change claims and only the server can do that using it's key)

Answer (score 0):

1. User roles usually represent the permissions or access levels that the user has, here are what this involves:

> Authentication: When a user logs in, they are checked if they are
> valid, they receive a token (usually a JWT token) that contains their
> UserRole within the payload.
>
> Authorization: After login, when the user tries to access a particular
> part of the application, the system checks the UserRole within the
> token to determine if they have the permissions.
>
> Role-Based Redirection: Based on the UserRole that is retrieved from
> the token, the application logic decides which page or controller the
> user should be redirected to.

2. Role validation, Token Validation, HTTP involved and Securing controller with policies will all make efforts to secure the routing.
3. User still won’t get the access if the token is intercepted and the role is changed to admin, since the secret set in your application will encode it and if the role is modified, the token signature still cannot be authorized.

[image]

In your code you try to add the role-based authorization policy. The 401 represents that it is not authorized, which is expected. So I start a sample app and you can check if it helps with your understanding. The main part is the **program.cs**

```
//role-based authorization
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("UserOnly", policy => policy.RequireRole("User"));
});
```

In the controller

```
[Route("api/fruits")]
[ApiController]
[Authorize(Policy = "UserOnly")]
public class FruitController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
    {
        var fruits = await Task.FromResult(new string[] { "apple", "bananana", "kiwi" });
        return Ok(fruits);
    }
}
```

Only authorized user can get the access to fruits.

[image]

There are also other official authorization policies like claim-based, policy-based. You can read the official documents for more details https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-8.0 .

Comment: I've implemented token validation in my authentication server, but I'm unsure about how to handle it on the client side, especially since my client doesn't have token validation in its program.cs. Should I include token validation there with a hardcoded signing key, or should I opt for a different approach? If I decide to request the API to validate the token for me, how can I go about making that request for validation? please see my system flow, i just include a picture link in the question. Thanks

Comment: i also have tried using this `builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
  .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
  {
    options.Authority = my Auth server address;
    options.Audience = my client address;
  });` but im getting error _System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'System.String'._

Comment: Better not validate the token on client side considering the secure issue. The client environment is not safe for your hardcoded signing key. In most http request models the client side only work on sending the token to server , which is more feasible and efficient. You can also customize the response in your webapi.